# Application did enter background function

Tags: cocoa-touch, nstimer, uiapplicationdelegate

Hey I got a pretty low interval timer in my firstViewController which I would like to terminate when the app enters background, but how am I supposed to access it from my Applications AppDelegate file where the function is located. I know this is extremely dumb question, but I would appreciate help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your firstViewController, you would listen for [UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-SW105).

In the firstViewController init method:

```
- (void)addObserver:(id)notificationObserver selector:(SEL)notificationSelector name:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender
```