# How can I tell when the device screen is locked?

Tags: ios, objective-c, locking, screen, avplayer

Is there anyway I can know if a user has locked the screen or not? I have two AVPlayers playing music, but I only want one of them to be able to play in the background. If I hooked up the lock screen to call a method, I could stop the AVPlayer before it plays in the background. Any direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: The answer here also applies to your situation -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5327278/application-did-enter-background-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the device is locked, -(void)applicationWillResignActive is called 
followed by -(void)applicationDidEnterBackground.

Write your code in the second method.

Answer (score 0):

When the screen is being locked, applicationDidEnterBackground will be called.
You can do your work there :)

Comment: I tried that, but for some reason it doesn't even trigger my NSLogs in the console....

Comment: That's weired... I just tried on IOS 7.0 and it's OK. What's your ios version?

Answer (score 0):

So I tried both suggestions of -(void)applicationWillResignActive and -(void)applicationDidEnterBackground, and it may work for you but for some reason it didn't even trigger my NSLogs in the console when i locked the screen. What would Trigger however is if I used NSNotifcationCenter.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                         selector: @selector(handleEnteredBackground)
                                             name: UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object: nil];
```

and then put the code I needed to run inside the selector.

```
-(void)handleEnteredBackground{
NSLog(@"This Shows inside the Console!");
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way to handle things, but it works for me, and might work for anyone else with the same issue, it is triggered by BOTH the Lock Screen Button and the Home Button on my iphone currently running iOS 7.0.4 which is just what I needed.